# Interface Initialization Does Not Initialize Superinterfaces

Tags: java, interface, jls

I found this code [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4), precisely `Example 12.4.1-3. Interface Initialization Does Not Initialize Superinterfaces`, a bit below of given address.

```
interface I {
    int i = 1, ii = Test.out("ii", 2);
}
interface J extends I {
    int j = Test.out("j", 3), jj = Test.out("jj", 4);
}
interface K extends J {
    int k = Test.out("k", 5);
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(J.i);
        System.out.println(K.j);
    }
    static int out(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

And the answer is:

```
1
j=3
jj=4
3
```

Question is: How is `jj=4` is printed?

Answer (score 1):

If the JVM needs to initialize the interface, then it will do *all* the initializations in the interface, not just the variable you were accessing.

In this case, it didn't need to initialize `I` because it was using a constant field in it, which does not trigger initialization, but it *did* need to initialize `J` because it was using `j`, which is not a compile-time constant expression. Doing that means both variables get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler convert `K.j` into `J.j`. So no actual reference to `K` in your code.

You don't see `ii=2` in your output because in `System.out.println(J.i);` value of `I.i` get inlined so no reference to `I` in your code.

Comment: Yes, but the question is , why `jj=4` is printed? Becausem `K.j` is `J.j` as you've sad, not `J.jj`, but `J.jj` is printed

Comment: I suppose if interface is processed all fields initialized from said interface.